# "null" in mathematical calculations?

Tags: mysql, null

I'm trying to make a MySQL query that returns rows where `(col_a+col_b-col_c+col_d) != col_e`, where all of the columns are `decimal` and default to `null`. There is one row that I know of that meets these requirements, but when I ran the query with the above logic as the `WHERE` clause, the row didn't show up. I noticed that `col_c` was `null`, instead of a numerical value, and after changing it to `0` the row showed up when I ran the query.

Why did this happen? I have always assumed that `null` was interpreted as `0` in an instance such as the above?

Comment: NULL != 0. IN fact NULL != NULL. Use `coalesce()` to make sure null values are set to zero before you do your math.

Comment: Not quite. Neither `NULL = 0` nor `NULL != 0` is true; similarly, neither `NULL = NULL` nor `NULL != NULL` is. (SQL uses a three-valued logic, whereby not all expressions are true or false.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` (as far as my interpretation goes) is unrepresentable data.  The only appropriate tests for null are [`IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) and several functions made specifically to handle `NULL` values: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

You could say `- IFNULL(col_c, 0)+col_d` (`COALESCE` will work identically in this case).

More information on working with `NULL`s: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize this. In PHP, `1+null==1` is true, but I just ran a query to check this in MySQL and as you said it's not true.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Is there any difference between `IFNULL` and `ISNULL`?

Comment: @retailcoder `ISNULL` returns 0 or 1.  `IFNULL` returns the first argument if it's not null, the second argument if it is

Comment: Hmmm I mean `ISNULL` not `IS NULL` - I've always been using `ISNULL` the way `IFNULL` is being used in your answer, as it does return the first argument if it's not null and the second if it is... in SQL Server at least. I'll do some research but I think they're four quarters for a dollar.

Comment: Found it! http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp - I hadn't noticed the `mysql` tag, turns out MySQL does not have a `ISNULL` function.

Answer (score 3):

Nate, NULL is NULL. MySQL is not going to do the type conversion automatically for you. A way around for that is change the table's column DEFAULT to 0. Or use a function IFNULL(col_c, 0) into your expression.

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do a mathematical calculation where one or more of the values might be `NULL` you need to account for it in the formula by using a numerical identity operation, since any calculation containing a `NULL` will have a result of `NULL`. Here are some common cases:

### Addition or Subtraction use 0

```
ifnull(col1,0)+ifnull(col2,0)
ifnull(col1,0)-ifnull(col2,0)
```

### Multiplication, Division, Exponents, or Modulus use 1

```
ifnull(col1,1)*ifnull(col2,1)
ifnull(col1,1)/ifnull(col2,1)
power(ifnull(col1,1),ifnull(col2,1))
mod(ifnull(col1,1),ifnull(col2,1))
```